# <![CDATA in SimplePie

Tags: php, cdata, simplepie

I've been working on some RSS **scraper** that parses data from multiple sources. That said, all this sources have their own implementation of the description of the RSS.

One in particular, uses CDATA tags to write the description on like, for example

```
<![CDATA[
<p align=justify><font face="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size=1>
<font color=#004080></font>
SOME TEXT GOES HERE 
 </font></p>
]]>
```

However if I try to get the item description with SimplePie I get this output

```
<div><p align="justify"></p></div>
```

I'm using this php script to do all this

```
 foreach($feed->get_Items() as $item)
 {
        
        $title = $item->get_title();
         $description = $item->get_description();
        //some other stuff
 }
```

And now the good part

The title on the feed comes also like this

```
<title>
  <![CDATA[ 
     Nice title
  ]]>
</title>
```

And... it works!!!

How can I get the description of the feed? I've tried almost everything!

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to [file a bug-report with SimplePie](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/issues/new). If you do please link/attach the original feed so it can be better reproduced.

Comment: So, I've stumbled across a bug?! Damn :(

I'll file a report then.

Comment: Well if it does not work like intended, I'd say it's a bug (or flaw). From what you posted I'd say it should have the text at least, but it is empty. And bugs are normal: We share the code, we share the bugs. Your help is needed! Please write a nice bugreport showing how to reproduce and providing all data for that (not only URLs but the real data). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [get_description()](http://simplepie.org/api/source-class-SimplePie_Item.html#308) and [get_content()](http://simplepie.org/api/source-class-SimplePie_Item.html#386) methods both do [sanitation](http://simplepie.org/api/source-class-SimplePie_Item.html#180) on the raw data, but you can use the [get_item_tags()](http://simplepie.org/api/class-SimplePie_Item.html#_get_item_tags) method to extract it untouched, like this:

```
$desc_tags = ($item->get_item_tags('', 'description')); // empty namespace is RSS2.0
if ($desc_tags) {
    print $desc_tags[0]['data'];
}
```

The only caveat is while the `get_content` or `get_description` will try to detect the namespace, you will have to provide it to `get_item_tags`, you can see the [namespace constants here](http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/supported_xml_namespaces). If you know the feeds format beforehand that should not be a problem, otherwise you might need to do the trial and error that the `get_description` do.

Comment: Why is it called sanitation when it actually breaks things?

Comment: Thank you!!! I actually am parsing this feed apart from the others, due to its "exquisite" nature. So, as this feed will remain RSS2 (so I think), and this code will only interfer with it, I find this solution to be acceptable! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might be running a different version than the latest, I've dumped the example description into a file and the result is `<p align="justify">SOME TEXT GOES HERE </p>` for me (bunch of whitespace omitted) font tags still killed however. It uses PHP DOM extension, so could be php version differences too.

Comment: Strange... I'm using the latest version, dowloaded from the site. Even with PHPDOM the results were the same...

Comment: @hakre Apologies, this is a bug! The point of it is to remove dangerous tags that could ruin your page.